# Fosuserbundle angular with token header request

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'am working on a project which has an API built with symfony2 as backend and front end app in Angular2. After logging in and getting token when I try to sent get request to my backend endpoint api this issue happend
-->FosUserbundle Username marc does not exist

I mentionne that my database have a table user with an recording user name marc
I think that is an FOSUSERBUNDLE security error any idea for solved it?

attached

[database user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRWkX.png)
[FOSUSERBUNDLE provider security.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRWYU.png)

thank you

Comment: how can I override to load by another property (useremail)

Comment: change security option `security.providers.id` to `fos_user.user_provider.username_email`

Comment: can you tell me more about where I have to do it please?

Comment: I'm  checked my setting  I already set my provider as your suggest

Comment: its work now after clear cache thank you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

`username_canonical` field should be "marc" too. `username_canonical` field contains canonical (lowercase) value of `username` field and is used to select user on login.

Comment: thank you but I changed it right now in my database  but kept same issue

Comment: I mentionne that when processing loggin I used email instead of username thank you